# Make Python error messages more verbose/detailed/specific - Is it possible?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm getting an error in several API calls after setting up a test environment on a different server. 99% Sure it's a MySQL thing, but the error that's returned isn't helpful at all:

```
global name 'sys' is not defined"
```

I've imported `sys` (and it works fine on my original, live version), and also tried to add `sys` to my `requirements.txt` on the new server, but apparently there's no pip/easy_install package for it.

Long story short, is there any way to make that error message return more information so I have a hope of debugging it? Thanks :)

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: I can't find the full traceback for some reason. The calls to the API that are returning this error are AJAX requests, and the response is just that error message (correctly as our API is written).

Comment: First, `sys` is part of the stdlib, and it's also special in it's largely just a namespace for a bunch of code that's already built in, so I wouldn't expect to find a pip package for it… If you don't have it, something is very wrong with your import path (which you could check with `sys.path`, except… yeah…).

Comment: Is it possible to get the output (including the full traceback) into a server log, instead of relying on what comes back over the network? Often that's just a matter of changing a config flag on your webserver/wsgi wrapper/whatever, but without knowing anything about your server it's pretty hard to suggest anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded, but my error is resolved. It turned out to be some weird permissions issue in the MySQL server settings.

I'm still curious if Python errors can be made more verbose, but I'm guessing the answer is not.

Comment: The traceback is about as verbose as base Python gets. If you have only the error message, you are being handicapped.

Comment: I hear ya. It turns out that because the exception was being handled by the code, it wasn't returning the traceback.